# populate document using javascript pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<table id="session">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <div class="borderContainer">
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <script type="template" id="thead">
            <div class="borderContainer">
                <div></div>
                <h3>{ColName}</h3>
            </div>
        </script>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <script type="template" id="tbody">
        <tr>
            <td class="row">
                <div class="borderContainer">
                    <div></div>
                    <h3>Row I</h3>
                </div>          
            </td>
            <!--
                When the parent pattern is appended to the DOM 
                populate the table additionally.
            -->
        </tr>
    </script>
</tbody>
</table>
```

There are two questions that I really would like two find the answer:

1.How to trigger event that tells me that since this pattern is populated it tells  that:
Now the page is ready for a second addition of content.
Or to paraphrase it : How to load dynamically content on two stages without DOM loading events affect the speed?

2.Is there a way to nest patterns or any other approach allowing to load contents dynamically on different levels of document hierarchy on one stage?

10x for your kind help

Comment: Which server, which language?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the questions. By "DOM loading events" do you mean additional HTTP requests? If so, then the content cannot loaded by Ajax which will always make HTTP requests. If you mean the stage where elements are added to the DOM, there will indeed be a performance hit if done client side. Adding nodes to the DOM always affects page performance. So are you looking to do everything server side (the javascript and jquery question tags wouldn't apply then)?

Answer (score 0):

1) AJAX libraries use a "callback" - which allows you to run some code upon completion of the request.

2) Not sure what you mean.